# Create File In Directory Error500

Tags: php, syntax, http-status-code-500

I am trying to create a file in a directory using PHP. Both the file and folder have CHMOD: 777. I am trying to make the file to be called image_ (the file count of a directory + 1)
My code is

```
    <button onclick="<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $directory = __DIR__ . "/images/"; $filecount = 0; $files = glob($directory . "*");  if ($files){ 
    $filecount = count($files); }
    $filecount = $filecount + 1;
    $pagename = 'image_'$filecount;

    $newFileName = './images/'.$pagename.;
    $newFileContent = '<?php echo "TEST"; ?>';
    if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    } else {
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    }
    ?> " class="">Upload</button>
```

I don't really know PHP and this is an amalgamation of code from different places.
What do I need to do to stop the ERROR 500

Comment: You need to _start_ with checking the error log, to find out what actually went wrong.

Comment: And also provide us any error you find in logs as mentioned @CBroe.
Read following answer to know where to find logs if you are using apache.https://askubuntu.com/a/14767

Comment: @Vicky. Thx but im not trying to make a folder, but a file inside a folder

Comment: @DominikDosoudil the error says 
    ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$filecount' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/vol6_8/epizy.com/epiz_28002566/htdocs/upload.php on line 82
```
Line 82 is
    ```$pagename = 'image_'$filecount;
```

Comment: I think that the problem is missing `.`. Try `'image_' . $filecount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one string concatenation at `$pagename = 'image_'$filecount;` and you are using one more in `$newFileName = './images/'.$pagename.;`.

Try to edit your PHP code like this

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $directory = __DIR__ . "/images/"; $filecount = 0; $files = glob($directory . "*");  if ($files){ 
    $filecount = count($files); }
    $filecount = $filecount + 1;
    $pagename = 'image_'.$filecount;

    $newFileName = './images/'.$pagename;
    $newFileContent = '<?php echo "TEST"; ?>';
    if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    } else {
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
    }
?>
```